# one ajax loop with 2 outputs error innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, function, innerhtml

Having a few issues trying to get this function output to an ajax table (working fine) and an input box called connectsList1.

i cannot get it to spit out into the input box without error, the error is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

and

> connectsList1 is not defined

```
 function getConnections(txt1) {

                    func_getConnections(
                function (response) {
                    var sortorder = txt1;
                    var arr = response;
                    var i;
                    var Count;
                    var mCount;
                    var oCount;
                    var out =
                       "<thead>"
                    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        out +=
                        "<tr>" +
                        "<tbody>" +
                        "<tr class=\"" + ReturnValuesAsColor(arr[i].o, arr[i].m, arr[i].server_proc) + "\">" +
                        "<td>" + arr[i].id + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + arr[i].user_id + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + arr[i].user_name + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + arr[i].workstation_name + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + (!!arr[i].ip_address ? arr[i].ip_address : '') + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + formatDateTime(arr[i].connect_date, 'datelongtime') + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + formatDateTime(arr[i].refresh_date, 'datelongtime') + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + (!!arr[i].app_ver ? arr[i].app_ver : '') + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + (!!arr[i].app_date ? formatDateTime(arr[i].app_date, 'shortdate') : '') + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + Messages_flag(arr[i].get_messages_flag) + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + FixNumbers(arr[i].message_type_flags) + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + arr[i].o + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + arr[i].m + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + arr[i].group_name + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + arr[i].server_proc + "</td>" +
                        "<td> <button id=\"DelImg1\" type=\"button\" name=\"btnsubmit\" class=\"ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all\" onclick=\"clearText('<%= result.ClientID%>'); CopyId(" + arr[i].id + "); return Message(" + arr[i].id + ")\"  >Delete</button> </td>" +
                        "</tr>" +
                        "</tbody>";

                        mCount = 0
                        if (arr[i].m != 0) {
                            mCount += 1;
                        } else if (arr[i].o != 0) {
                            oCount += +1;
                        } else if (arr[i].o == 0 & arr[i].m == 0) {
                            Count += 1;
                        }

                        document.getElementById("dtBody1").innerHTML = out;

                        document.getElementById('ConnectsList1').innerHTML = out;

                        ConnectsList1 = "      Connection list: " & Count + oCount + mCount & " connection(s)     Main Application : " & Count & "     Online : " & oCount & "     Mobile : " & mCount;
                    }})};
```

Any help or advice welcome, still learning ajax myself

Comment: Well, do you have an element in the DOM with `id="dtBody1"`? Do you have an element with `id="ConnectsList1"`? Also note that it makes no sense to have a loop repeatedly overwriting the `innerHTML` property of an element, as subsequent loop iterations will overwrite whatever the previous loop iteration wrote.

Comment: In general, the **first thing** to do when faced with this sort of thing is use the fully-featured debugger built into your browser to step through the code line by line, example variables and the state of the DOM at various stages, etc.

Comment: yeh i have both those elements in the DOM. Still working out the loop and but will have a look at that, thanks. Been using the debugger in chrome. Its  repeatedly overwriting the innerHTML because its calling a stored proc to update a live connections list. I will have another look at the debugger

Comment: *"yeh i have both those elements in the DOM"* With apologies, but clearly you **don't** as of when this code is run, or `getElementById` wouldn't be returning `null` and you wouldn't be getting the first error you list.

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementById("dtBody1")` can not find any tag with id `dtBody1`. Make sure your HTML has an element with that ID.
And remember to declare the `ConnectsList1` variable to avoid the second error.